# ¿Como hacer deploy desde un repositorio en bitbucket server?

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket

Tengo un servidor con bitbucket server instalado (un servidor propio), ya creamos un repositorio con la aplicación, sin embargo, ahora necesitamos que los cambios que ocurran en el repositorio se vean reflejados en la aplicación de forma automática. 
En otro proyecto teníamos git y mediante un hook post-receive se realizaba un rsync del repo hacia la aplicación.

Para bitbucket vi en la documentación que se necesita escribir el propio hook con java, pero no me queda claro, donde se coloca dicho hook, como lo invoco, como le indico que repositorio quiero y hacia que carpeta de van a copiar los cambios?

Este link encontré: https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/how-tos/repository-hooks.html

Muchas gracias por toda su ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Peter. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Sobre el link que encontraste, se describe el problema? ¿Qué inconveniente tuviste siguiéndolo? ¿Buscaste en algún otro lado?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses [Dandelion](https://github.com/scttnlsn/dandelion).

Es fácil de instalar y sólo tiene que editar `dandelion.yml`, que luce como lo siguiente:

```
adapter: sftp
host: example.com
username: user
password: pass
path: path/to/deployment

exclude:
    - .gitignore
    - dandelion.yml
    - dir/

additional:
    - config/auth.yml
```

Lo mejor de todo es que lo puedes usar con repositorios **github** o con **bitbucket** porque funciona con git.

Y el `deploy` lo haces desde el directorio del repositorio, de la siguiente manera:

```
dandelion deploy
```

**Nota:** los css y js se deben agregar en el `additional`

```
additional:
  - css/app.min.css
  - javascripts/app.min.js
  - javascripts/init.min.js
```